# MYSQL get records from yesterday with a timeshift

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get records from "yesterday" in MYSQL but there is a catch.  "Yesterday" is defined from 8am yesterday and 8am TODAY (prior to open of business).

The standard way to get yesterday is:

```
 where timestamp BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()
```

But how can I shift this to the 8am to 8am time frame that I am concerned with?  This is dynamic so I can't use between with hard coded time frames.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `concat(curdate(), ' 8:00:00')` instead of `curdate()`...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dynamic"? Just that you need to use `CURDATE()` or that the day may change from 8am-8am to some other time period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just subtract 16 hours or add 8 hours to `CURDATE()` to get your desired time window e.g.

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 16 HOUR, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
```

Output:

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 16 HOUR    CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
2018-12-10 08:00:00             2018-12-11 08:00:00
```

So your `WHERE` clause would become

```
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 16 HOUR, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
```

Comment: Just curious, is this syntax valid for all MySQL versions, or you need to use `DATE_ADD()` on previous ones? +1

Comment: @Shidersz I'm pretty sure it's valid on all 5.x versions too. See e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals. Also in 5.1 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/functions.html#function_date-add